# Keep Getting Black OSM Tiles in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

When trying to view OSM tiles using the external storage example of OpenLayers, 
I keep getting black tiles when I zoom in and out.

I don't know what the issue is but every time I zoom in/out there are black tiles that appear.

Please help me.

Comment: Which OSM server are you using? Any error messages? Which version(s) of arcmap?

Comment: Sorry Bro...OpenLayers-2.12 ...I am using the Offline Storage Example ..and I get no error .. :(

Comment: So you are not using arcmap? Are you using http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/offline-storage.html or a local instance?

Comment: Local Instance and when i upload it on my server...

Comment: What do you see in your server logs? Does it work correctly on the openlayers example site I linked to?

Comment: There is absolutely no error on the server log or in the Firebug. The black Tiles keep rendering everytime .an yes your link is working fine..

Comment: Can you please try and investigate at least a bit? Are the images not being returned, are they returning black tiles, or something else? Are you violating same-origin policy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886107/openlayers-format-json-is-returning-empty-responsetext-string)